# Plotting data series with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a csv file `index.dat` with data

```
Year,0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+
2000,100,100,100,100,100,100
2001,101,102,101,102,101,102
...
```

I am trying to plot this with `pgfplots`.

I have made this script

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    grid=both,
    xmin=2000,
    xmax=2010,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=, rotate=45},
    ymin=80,
]

\addplot table [x=Year, y=0-19 years, col sep=comma] {./data/index.dat};
\addlegendentry{0-19 years}

\addplot table [x=Year, y=20-39 years, col sep=comma] {./data/index.dat};
\addlegendentry{20-39 years}

\addplot table [x=Year, y=40-59 years, col sep=comma] {./data/index.dat};
\addlegendentry{40-59 years}

\addplot table [x=Year, y=60-79 years, col sep=comma] {./data/index.dat};
\addlegendentry{60-79 years}

\addplot table [x=Year, y=80-99 years, col sep=comma] {./data/index.dat};
\addlegendentry{80-99 years}

\addplot table [x=Year, y=100 years+, col sep=comma] {./data/index.dat};
\addlegendentry{100 years+}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

and it works fine, but I think it's a bit stupid way to do it.

Can I do the same by just specifying that I want to plot all columns from 2 to 7 and use column 1 as x values?

Comment: I guess this can be done by using some \foreach statements. I'll try if you're so kind to provide a working MWE

Comment: You've posted a lot of questions and many of them have acceptable answers, but alas, you're not accepting them (at least in most cases :-( ) -- this not how TeX.SX works!

Comment: Also, please provide a complete (compilable) MWE, not just a snippet, so it's easy for others to copy-paste the provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A Simple Loop

First of all I would read the table once using `\pgfplotstableread` into a macro and reuse this macro.  This speeds up the typesetting and saves you some typing in the case that the location, name, or format of the file changes.

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{index.dat}\loadedtable
```

Since you are doing exactly the same thing for each column, viz. plotting and adding the column name to the legend, I would suggest to just loop over all the columns.

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+}{
  \addplot table [x=Year, y=#1, col sep=comma] {\loadedtable};
  \addlegendentry{#1}
}
```

Caution! You have to use either `\pgfplotsungroupedforeach` or `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` here.  The classic TikZ `\foreach` will *not* work straightforwardly.

You have only provided the first two samples of data, which is why the output looks a little bit ridiculous.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{index.dat}
Year,0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+
2000,100,100,100,100,100,100
2001,101,102,101,102,101,102
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    grid=both,
    xmin=2000,
    xmax=2010,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=, rotate=45},
    ymin=80,
    ]
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{index.dat}\loadedtable
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+}{
      \addplot table [x=Year, y=#1] {\loadedtable};
      \addlegendentry{#1}
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

## More than One Loop Variable

If you additionally want to assign a certain style (color, mark, etc.) to the plots in the loop, you will have to use `\foreach`, because `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` allows only a single variable.  The downside is that in contrast to `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`, where `#1` is simply *replaced* by the content of the loop variable, for `\foreach` you have to explicitly expand the loop variable in an `\edef` context (That is the pitfall with `\foreach` I was referring to above).  The loop hence transforms to

```
\foreach \col/\style in {%
  0-19 years/{red,dashed,mark options={red}},
  20-39 years/{blue},
  40-59 years/{green},
  60-79 years/{yellow},
  80-99 years/{magenta},
  100 years+/{cyan}
} {
  \edef\temp{%
    \noexpand\addplot+[\style] table [x=Year, y=\col] {\noexpand\loadedtable};
    \noexpand\addlegendentry{\col}
  }
  \temp
}
```

The full example is then

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{index.dat}
Year,0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+
2000,100,100,100,100,100,100
2001,101,102,101,102,101,102
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    grid=both,
    xmin=2000,
    xmax=2010,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=, rotate=45},
    ymin=80,
    ]
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{index.dat}\loadedtable
    \foreach \col/\style in {%
      0-19 years/{red,dashed,mark options={red}},
      20-39 years/{blue},
      40-59 years/{green},
      60-79 years/{yellow},
      80-99 years/{magenta},
      100 years+/{cyan}
    } {
      \edef\temp{%
        \noexpand\addplot+[\style] table [x=Year, y=\col] {\noexpand\loadedtable};
        \noexpand\addlegendentry{\col}
      }
      \temp
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

## Cycle Lists

Another viable alternative (which I would favour) is creating a custom cycle list for colours.  In a cycle list, `pgfplots` picks the next entry automatically on each plot and repeats, when the list has reached its end.  To define a cycle list use

```
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{custom}{%
  red,mark=*\\blue,mark=square*\\green,mark=otimes*\\%
  yellow,mark=star\\magenta,mark=diamond*\\cyan,mark=*\\%
}
```

The entries in the cycle list are delimited by `\\`.  It is important to hide the linebreak after `\\` with a `%`.  In an entry you can specify colours, marks, and other options, such as linestyles.  For this example I went with colours and marks.  After defining the cycle list (before the `axis` environment) you have to tell the `axis` to actually use it by adding `cycle list name=custom` to the options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{index.dat}
Year,0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+
2000,100,100,100,100,100,100
2001,101,102,101,102,101,102
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{custom}{%
    red,mark=*\\blue,mark=square*\\green,mark=otimes*\\%
    yellow,mark=star\\magenta,mark=diamond*\\cyan,mark=*\\%
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    grid=both,
    xmin=2000,
    xmax=2010,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=, rotate=45},
    ymin=80,
    cycle list name=custom
    ]
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{index.dat}\loadedtable
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+}{
      \addplot table [x=Year, y=#1] {\loadedtable};
      \addlegendentry{#1}
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! That's great. But now I don't have the ability to choose which colors to use. Do you know if it's possible to specify which color mix to use?

Comment: @Jamgreen See updated answer.